# Python Executing remote ssh command

Tags: python, linux, ssh

I'm writing a python nagios check to check the timestamp of a file the last time it was updated, however I need to check two separate hosts in my script so I want to use a remote ssh command to return the timestamp to stdout and use that to make sure a script has completed within the last 24 hours because when the script completes it touches a file.

When I run the command from command prompt it works however when I run it from my python code it doesn't return the output back to my program.

```
Grants-MacBook-Pro:test GrantZukel$ ssh ubuntu@hostname sudo ls -la /home/ubuntu/ | grep code_regen_complete

The authenticity of host 'ec2-54-144-160-238.compute-1.amazonaws.com (54.144.160.238)' can't be established.

RSA key fingerprint is hidden.

Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)? yes

Failed to add the host to the list of known hosts (/Users/GrantZukel/.ssh/known_hosts).

-rw-r--r-- 1 root   root       0 Jan 29 17:23 code_regen_complete

Grants-MacBook-Pro:test GrantZukel$
```

The python is :

```
def get_code_time(): 
    p = subprocess.Popen(['ssh','ubuntu@hostname', '"sudo ls -la /home/ubuntu/ | grep code_regen_complete"'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    out, err = p.communicate()
    m = re.search('\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}\s+\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}', out)
    return m.group(0)
```

however when I use debugger the out or err vars are completely empty. Any ideas?

Comment: unrelated, but if you log in as `ubuntu`, why do you need to `sudo` to list `/home/ubuntu`?

Comment: and why don't you `ls -l /home/ubuntu/code_regen_complete` directly?

Answer (score 2):

You need to pass `shell=True` in your command :

```
p = subprocess.Popen(['ssh','ubuntu@hostname', '"sudo ls -la /home/ubuntu/ | grep code_regen_complete"'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE,shell=True)
```

Comment: Thanks this worked I still had to modify a few things but this ultimately is what helped thanks.

Comment: one more qeustion tho

Comment: sudo ssh ubuntu@hosts sudo git log -1 --date=iso | grep ^Date: | awk '{print $2','$3, $4}'      how do i execute that command against /var/www/vhosts/webdirectory

Comment: local_repo_date = compare_codebase("sudo ssh ubuntu@hostname 'cd /var/www/vhosts/bazumedia.com/;  sudo git log -1 --date=iso | grep ^Date'")    I figured it out nvm

Answer (score 1):

Get rid of the double-quotes around the `ls` command:

```
p = subprocess.Popen(['ssh','ubuntu@hostname', 'sudo ls -la /home/ubuntu/code_regen_complete'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
```

You might also want to try [Fabric](http://www.fabfile.org/).